# Delphi using sql with parameters error

Tags: sql-server, delphi

I have following code;

```
  Dm.QrTmp.SQL.Add('(Select sum (sth.sth_tutar+sth.sth_vergi) from    
  '+MikActiveDb+'STOK_HAREKETLERI sth ');
  Dm.QrTmp.SQL.Add('where (sth.sth_tarih>= :ptar1 and sth.sth_tarih<= :ptar2)  ');
```

I have set parameters like this.

```
  Dm.QrTmp.Parameters.ParamByName('ptar1').DataType := ftDate;
  Dm.QrTmp.Parameters.ParamByName('ptar2').DataType := ftDate;
  Dm.QrTmp.Parameters.ParamByName('ptar1').Value := Tarih1.Value;
  Dm.QrTmp.Parameters.ParamByName('ptar2').Value := Tarih2.Value;
```

But in run time delphi give me an error ;

```
Parameter object is improperly defined. Inconsistent or incomplete information was provided.
```

Comment: Tarih1 and Tarih2 are component and they can have date/time/datetime type values. In this code they have date values.

Comment: Assuming that you are using ADO based dataset component and your field is of type [`date`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630352.aspx) (both should have been mentioned, along with a Delphi version tag, in your question), follow e.g. [`this post`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19855691/960757).

Comment: Yes. It is a adoquery, fields are date dtype field and im using xe7

Comment: According the link you proposed i have changed code and it worked. But it doesnt worked when i used ptar1 and ptar2 in second sentence. So i have tried with second sentence for ptar3 and ptar4 then it has worked. 

Now the question is can we use a defined parameter in sql twice or not?

Comment: no you can't use a parameter twice, just define a new one and set the same value.